# How to get a User's Group from Azure Active Directory after Authentication

Tags: php, laravel, azure-active-directory

After registering an app in my azure active directory, i can get the user in a callback :

```
    object(Magium\ActiveDirectory\Entity)#262 (1) {
  ["data":protected]=>
  array(16) {
    ["aud"]=> string(36) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ["iss"]=> string(75) "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/v2.0"
    ["iat"]=> int(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
    ["nbf"]=> int(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
    ["exp"]=> int(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
    ["aio"]=> string(140) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ["email"]=> string(20) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com"
    ["idp"]=> string(61) "https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/"
    ["name"]=> string(13) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ["oid"]=> string(36) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ["preferred_username"]=> string(20) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com"
    ["sub"]=> string(43) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ["tid"]=> string(36) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ["uti"]=> string(22) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ["ver"]=> string(3) "2.0"
    ["access_token"]=> string(1910) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

but how do i access the group he belongs to which i have declared in my azure active directory?
ps: the code to get the user is this:

```
    @php
session_start();



$config = [
    'authentication' => [
    'ad' => [
        'client_id' => 'xxxxxxx',
        'client_secret' => 'xxxxxxx',
        'enabled' => 'yes',
        'directory' => "xxxxxxx",
        'return_url' => 'xxxxxxx'

        ]
    ]
];

$request = new \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request();

$ad = new \Magium\ActiveDirectory\ActiveDirectory(
    new \Magium\Configuration\Config\Repository\ArrayConfigurationRepository($config),
    Zend\Psr7Bridge\Psr7ServerRequest::fromZend(new \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request())
);

$entity = $ad->authenticate();
echo $entity->getName() . '<Br />';
echo $entity->getPreferredUsername() . '<Br />';
@endphp
```

I clicked on Azure Active Directory-> Groups -> Create a group -> add users -> done.
Thats how i created the group.
But in my callback for the user i cant get it to work.
I am completely clueless please help.
Thanks a ton guys!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a **memberOf** attribute which it seems is not present. If you are using openLDAP, **memberof** attribute is hidden by default. Check that setting once. Also make sure that anonymous access is allowed for this attribute.

Comment: excuse me, please what?